# Repetition pattern match

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match a word "some" in " i want somesomesome pies" and replace any string matches it with a concatenation with {..} so it's output should be "i want {somesomesome} pies" but mine is "i want {some} pies".

Here is my regex:

> (some)*some

Comment: How are you actually doing the replacement?

Comment: What you use for the replacement string, `{$1}`?  If you use `{$0}` instead, you should get the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One sample as below:

```
    String some = "some";
    String input = "i want somesomesome pies, and some apples, and somesomesomesome pears";
    // at least one 'some' word
    System.out.println(input.replaceAll("((?:"+some+")+)", "{$1}"));
    // at least two 'some' word
    System.out.println(input.replaceAll("((?:"+some+"){2,})", "{$1}"));
```

The output is:

```
i want {somesomesome} pies, and {some} apples, and {somesomesomesome} pears
i want {somesomesome} pies, and some apples, and {somesomesomesome} pears
```